# Get video duration from URL of format m3u8 in Android app?

Tags: java, android, jwplayer

i have used both MediaMetadataRetriever and FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever but it doesn't work m3u8 format. i think FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever doesn't support m3u8 format. Is there any other solution to get the duration of m3u8 videoformat url? Thank you in advance
    Using FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mFFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
        mFFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever .setDataSource("http://103.213.31.46/devtest/andPICTURE450.stream/playlist_dvr.m3u8");
        String mVideoDuration =  mFFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever .extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever .METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
        long mTimeInMilliseconds= Long.parseLong(mVideoDuration);
        mFFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.release();
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + mTimeInMilliseconds);
```

using MediaMetadataRetriever

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
//use one of overloaded setDataSource() functions to set your data source
retriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
long timeInMillisec = Long.parseLong(time );

retriever.release()
```

Comment: can you please share your code for people to help.

Comment: @Tenzing, have you got the solution ?

Comment: Using the PlayerView getDuration() function you can get the url total duration but duration is calculated only after the url is played. hope it helps. @Priya

Comment: thank u.. its working